# EC2 - adding a second interface andpPrivat IP results in no link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm currently trying to find out why I'm unable to get a working network link within my Ubuntu ec2 instance secondary >>interface<<. I have one VPC with two Subnets in it. The first subnet is my management network which runs on a dedicated interface, the primary interface (ens5).
Now I added a second network interface to all my ec2 instances (ens6), this interfaces is attached to my GlusterFS subnet with a different CIDR range than the primary one, see below.

ens5: 10.10.10.0/24
ens6: 172.10.10.0/24

The problem now is that ens5 always has a link and routes fine and ens6 does not have a IP attached:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:a1:07:fa:2d:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.241/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 2185sec preferred_lft 2185sec
    inet6 fe80::a1:7ff:fefa:2dcc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:04:0a:df:1c:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I already watched this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmwGYXchb4E
but it seems that its only about adding a second IP to the primary interface, which is not what I wanted.

How can I simply add a second network interface and IP to all my EC2 instances?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or is such a scenario only possible by a second VPC?

Comment: Which AMI are you using?

Comment: simply ubuntu 18.04 HVM x86_64